# SQL Server 2008 - Find out on which data row the error (divide by zero) appeared

Tags: sql-server

i have a query running on a large amount of data in SSMS. After about 20 minutes of execution, the query completes with an error 'Divide by zero' (some results are already returned).

It would be helpful to know on which data the error appeared, i.e. find the id/row nuber on which the error can be reproduced.

The query itself is rather complicated, so i am not going to post it; the question is more technical - is there a log somewhere, or another way to find the problematic row(s)?

Comment: No. Can you figure it out from the rows already returned? i.e. if 780 have been returned to the client I guess the problem is on row 781

Comment: can't you just modify your select so that it selects the divisor instead of using it to divide with?

Comment: I am using a stored procedure in the query and the error probably comes from inside it. The row number (id) of the row where the error appeared would be helpful in debugging.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select
   *,
   Dividend / NULLIF(Divisor, 0) as NullIfBollixedNow
FROM
   MyTable
-- to isolate the rows(s). Without this, you get NULL instead of error in the output
WHERE
    Dividend / NULLIF(Divisor, 0) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server there isn't an easy way to do this as Ordering or other functions may affect the row order after the Put in some exception handling into your procedure using case statements and output an exception value on the broken rows. Something like this

If you query was

```
Select MyFirstField / MySecondField as TestMath
From myTblOfFacts

Select
Case when MySecondField > 0 then MyFirstField / MySecondField
Else -1
End as TestMath
From myTblOfFacts
```

THis would return -1 for the rows with an issue.